# How can I add a sapUI5 Panel without syle-information in a XML-View?

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

In my XML-View I added a `<Panel>` that iterates over the elements of the data-binding:

```
<mvc:View
    ...
    xmlns="sap.m"
>
    <Panel content="{/}">
        <Panel headerText="{Item Header}">
             <Text text="{Item Text}"></Text>
        </Panel>
    </Panel>
</mvc:View>
```

This gives me

[image]

How can I remove the formating (bg-color, padding/margin, ...) of the outer `<Panel>`? Is there a 'plain' element in ui5 like a `<div>` in HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The `sap.m.Panel` has a property `backgroundDesign`.

The default value is `Translucent`, maybe `Transparent` fits better in your situation.

https://openui5beta.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Panel/properties

Answer (score 0):

I found `<VBox>` useful to solve the issue (note: use `items=...` instead of `content=...`):

```
<mvc:View
    ...
    xmlns="sap.m"
>
    <VBox items="{/}">
        <Panel headerText="{Item Header}">
             <Text text="{Item Text}"></Text>
        </Panel>
    </Panel>
</mvc:View>
```

This gives

[image]